# Getting multiple IF statement clauses to work together

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, func

I am building an iOS quiz app and depending on certain key words that appear in the question label I want the background photo to change corresponding to the key word in the question. For example, if the question label contains the word "food" I would want the background picture to always show a picture of an apple. If the question label contains the word "fruit" I also want the background picture to be that same apple as for the key word "food". However when I run my code it only works properly if I use only ONE key word.

```
 //this code works and changes the background picture appropriately
 func quizImage() {

 if (questionLabel.text?.contains("food"))!

   //applePicture is the name of the image
  { questionImage.image = applePicture }

   }
```

However when I try the following ,to use multiple if clauses, the background photo doesn't change at all, even if one of the key words appear  in the question label

```
  func quizImage() {

   //this code doesn't work and the background photo never changes
  if (questionLabel.text?.contains("food"))!,(questionLabel.text?.contains("apple"))!

   { questionImage.image = applePicture}

   }
```

Any help of advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use comma(,) then it will be true only if both the conditions satisfies. Do like this,

```
if let text = questionLabel.text, (text.contains("food") || text.contains("apple")) {
    questionImage.image = applePicture
}
```

Comment: How can I better change this @Cristik?

Comment: @Cristik fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Venkat. I upvtoted I just don't have high enough reputation to change it yet.

Comment: @Venkat - what about contains concept

Comment: but i am checking `questionLabel.text != nil` this will take care. after this even if u use ! that will not make any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap those two variants in an array, and use the `contains` function:

```
if let text = questionLabel.text, ["food", "apple"].contains(where: { text.contains($0) }) {
    questionImage.image = applePicture
}
```

This will reduce the code duplication, and it's scalable in case that later on you will need to cover more that 2 variants.

Comment: sorry same as Venkat